# Unable to connect SQL Server using server name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

specs
version - sql server 2008 r2 sp1
servername - server1
ipaddress - 192.168.1.10

So here's what's happening,

I have 2 servers: 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.10

- if I remote 192.168.1.1 and connect to SQL Server using SSMS and use 192.168.1.10 it can connect (works fine)
- if I remote 192.168.1.1 and connect to SQL Server using SSMS and use server1 it cannot connect.
- if I remote 192.168.1.10 and connect to SQL Server using SSMS and use server1 it can connect (works fine)
- if I remote 192.168.1.10 and connect to SQL Server using SSMS and use 192.168.1.10 it can connect (works fine)

Given server1 has

- ping to server 192.168.1.1 works
- telnet works
- tcp/ip enabled.
- namedpipes enabled.
- firewall to local group is disabled.
- firewall port exception to 1433 (default)

Comment: This could be a DNS issue.  Can you ping `server1` from `192.168.1.1`? I'm guessing no

Comment: i can ping "server1" name from 192.168.1.1 just fine.

Comment: @Juvil, do You have named instance on `server1` like `server1\<name>` ? If so You have to adjust firewall - add  UDP 1434 port.